# How can I dynamically generate pages in Next.js using data from a custom API endpoint, while maintaining the key features

Tags: reactjs, next.js

How can I dynamically generate pages in Next.js using data from a custom API endpoint, while maintaining the key features provided by Next.js such as automatic code splitting, optimized performance, and SEO optimization?

Here's an example scenario: let's say I have an e-commerce website built with Next.js, and I want to dynamically generate a product detail page for each of the items in my product catalog. The product information is stored in a database and can be accessed through an API endpoint at https://my-api.com/products/:id, where :id is the ID of the product.

To accomplish this, I need to be able to call the API endpoint in my Next.js application and pass the product information to a component that will render the product detail page. At the same time, I want to take advantage of the benefits provided by Next.js, such as automatic code splitting, which means that the JavaScript, CSS, and other assets for the product detail page should only be loaded when the user navigates to that page, and not when the user visits other pages on the site.

What is the best way to implement this functionality in Next.js, while preserving the automatic code splitting, optimized performance, and SEO optimization provided by the framework?

Here's an example of what the code for the product detail page may look like:

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

function ProductDetail({ product }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{product.name}</h1>
      <p>{product.description}</p>
      <p>Price: {product.price}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

ProductDetail.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  const { id } = ctx.query
  const res = await axios.get(`https://my-api.com/products/${id}`)
  const product = res.data

  return { product }
}

export default ProductDetail
```

Comment: Server-Side-Routing (SSR) will build your dynamic page on the server at run time. Nextjs is designed to optimize this page by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the guide on [Next.js Dynamic Routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes). Imagine you want to handle a blog with many posts where each post has it's own unique slug.

Then you would dynamically handle unknown slugs using this literal filename:

`pages/post/[...slug].js`